# How to construct a string value inside a nested jinja template?

Tags: jinja2

I want to be able to generate three set of codes, each for a different environment. The name environment is passed via a `flavor` variable.

```
{% with flavor="dev" %}
  {% include "inner.j2" %}
{% endwith %}

{% with flavor="uat" %}
  {% include "inner.j2" %}
{% endwith %}

{% with flavor="prod" %}
  {% include "inner.j2" %}
{% endwith %}
```

Inside the `inner.j2`, it will pass a set of variable to a underlying generic template `timeseries.j2`

```
 # inner.j2
{%- set graph = "timeseries.j2" -%}

{%- with
  title = "aws.rds.free_storage_space",
  queries = [
    {{ "avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:" + flavor + "-db-read-0}" }} ,

    "avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:dev-db-read-1}",
    "avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:dev-db-read-2}",
    "avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:dev-db-master}",
    "avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:dev-db-migration}",
    "avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:dev-db-reports}",
    "avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:dev-db-cross-region}"
  ],
  type = "line"
-%}

{#################################
  Do not change below this line
##################################}
{%- macro indenting() -%}
{%- include graph -%}
{%- endmacro -%}
{{ indenting() | trim | indent(2) }}
{%- endwith -%}
```

I want to be able to construct the `queries` variable in `inner.j2` by some kind of string manipulation.

My attempt above is this:

```
{{ "avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:" + flavor + "-db-read-0}" }}
```

And it throws this exception

```
  File "/Users/antkong/Documents/Personal/wd/StackoverflowCode/python/jinja/inner.j2", line 6, in template
    {{ "avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:" + flavor + "-db-read-0}" }} ,
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only need

```
"avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:" + flavor + "-db-read-0}"
```

The enclosing '{{' and '}}' are causing the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
{{ "avg:aws.rds.free_storage_space{name:%s-db-read-0}" %(flavor) }}
```

Comment: It throws this exception `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'`